# VS code Settings are not show

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am not friendly with Vs Code but i Came to this IDE because you can use any language in just less than 1 GB
but when open Settings both 2 Tabs are Not shown properly how i resolve it.
I restart My PC. I Reinstall Vs code but Nothing Happerns.
The Screenshot is :
Please Help.[This Is My Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tO4h.png)

Comment: Disable ALL your extensions (`...` menu in Extensions View) and try again, restart VSC

Comment: But i need code runner extension and problem occur with this extension only

Comment: if you see the settings screen with all extensions disabled, and not when you enable one it is a problem with that extension and not with VSC